# How to Allow VBA Code to Run in Read-Only PowerPoint File?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint file that is password protected, because quite frankly the operators interacting with the file are computer illiterate, and may accidentally destroy the file if it is editable.

I should say, before I get much deeper... I searched and found this question, which has a solution that won't work in this case:  [Click Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827650/how-to-provide-vba-access-for-a-modify-password-protected-read-only-powerpoint-f)

I wrote a simple VBA script that allows them to search for part number, rather than using the PowerPoint slides to find the correct part number (this goes back to not being used to computers or even knowing what PowerPoint is).

At any rate, the script works well on my computer, but obviously I have to enter the password to edit the VBA code.  When I try to run the code in read-only mode, I get an error `"Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'  Presentation (unknown member) : Invalid request.  Presentation cannot be modified."`

Essentially, I am seeing that the code cannot be executed with the file in read-only mode.

The error actually occurs in this snippet of code:

```
'Follow the hyperlink to opent the correct file
    If Len(Dir$(ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & sFile)) > 0 Then
        ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink Address:=sFile
    Else
        MsgBox "No file exists at path " & ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & sFile
    End If
```

on the line `ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink Address:=sFile`.

Anything I can do to open the pdf file in a different way, with the presentation in read-only mode?

Comment: Why didn't the linked question/solution work in this case?

Comment: I can't unprotect the sheet as it is too risky.  In the past, some of our employees have, in good faith, were trying to correct a problem, and ended up reprogramming a DC torque tool.  I would like to completely avoid the confusion and headache of someone accidentally messing up the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a password protected file w/o supplying the password.
To open the file in VBA by supplying the password, you can do this:

Set oPres = Presentations.Open("c:\temp\open.pptx::pwd::")

where c:\temp\open.pptx is the path to the file and pwd is the password.

Since this'd open the file, your colleagues could still edit it, so you might consider copying the real file to their temp folder, possibly under some unlikely namae, and opening the copy rather than the original. And then deleting any existing copy the next time they run any of your code.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding why it will not open, as I am opening a separate file (a pdf file) than the password protected PowerPoint file.  The PPT file is opened once and stays open.

Comment: Have you considered using ShellExecute to launch the PDF?  If you google for that plus VBA you'll find some examples.