# VBA Powerpoint - Open Password Protected File as Protected Window from OneDrive Folder

Tags: vba, powerpoint

**What I want to to:**
I have a password protected Powerpoint file (Password is "abc"). I want to open this file via VBA in protected mode. The file is saved in a local directory (hard drive) under PPT_PATH.

***Addition / Update:**
After digging deeper into the problem it has shown that the error only occurs when the file is saved in a **local OneDrive folder**. When saved in a non-OneDrive folder the code works fine.
I get the actual local OneDrive path of the PPT file for PPT_PATH - not the url - so this should not cause the defect.*

**What I have done:**
I have defined a ProtectedViewWindow

```
Dim PVW As ProtectedViewWindow
```

I then try to open the Password protected file by using the open method of the PVW

```
Set PVW = ProtectedViewWindows.Open(PPT_PATH, "abc")
```

This then throws an error "The Method 'Open' for the Object 'ProtectedViewWindows' has failed (Runtime Error -2147467259 (800004005))".
The code works fine when I try to open the file as long as it's not password protected. Hence I would like to understand, what I'm missing.

**Where I need help:**
I would like to be able to open the password protected file in protected mode

Comment: You need to supply the password when opening.  Have a look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827650/how-to-provide-vba-access-for-a-modify-password-protected-read-only-powerpoint-f/45334689#45334689 , specifically the bit that explains using .Open ("C:\PowerPoint\PW_prot_file.pptm::password::")  Note that the password is ::password:: and not :password:: as explained in the linked article.

Comment: The syntax for PowerPoint VBA is slightly different from Excel so putting 
'Set PVW = ProtectedViewWindows.Open(PPT_PATH, "abc")' 
or 
'Set PVW = ProtectedViewWindows.Open(FileName:=PPT_PATH, ReadPassword:="abc")' are syntactically correct and should work.

-> I have updated the questions as I dig deeper into the causes